Bullet Physics stopping model from going through static object
Bullet physics tunneling problem:
yellow box(dimensions: 2f, 2f, 2f) that falls under gravity. Its Bullet Physics are set as such:
btCollisionShape btBox = new btBoxShape(vectorToScale.scl(0.5f)/*dimensions.scl(0.5f)*/); //notice we take halves!
    Vector3 localInertia = new Vector3();
    btBox.calculateLocalInertia(yellowBoxMass,localInertia);
    //btBox.setMargin(0.4f);
    MotionStateForPhys msphys = new MotionStateForPhys(yellowInstance.transform);
    btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo info = new btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(yellowBoxMass,null,btBox,localInertia);
    btYellowBody = new btRigidBody(info);
    btYellowBody.setMotionState(msphys);

dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(btYellowBody);
    
    btYellowBody.activate();

The floor physics where the box is supposed to land and NOT go through:
btBoxShape btBox = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(10,1f,10)); //notice we take halves!
        
        btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo info = new btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(0,null,btBox,Vector3.Zero);
        btBodyForFloor= new btRigidBody(info);
        //btBodyForFloor.setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_NO_CONTACT_RESPONSE/*|btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_STATIC_OBJECT*/);
        //btBodyForFloor.setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject.CollisionFlags.CF_STATIC_OBJECT);

        btBodyForFloor.setWorldTransform(floorInstance.transform);          

        dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(btBodyForFloor);

The Physics important objects that run the simulation:
collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
        btDispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
        btInterface = new btDbvtBroadphase();
        solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
        dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(btDispatcher,btInterface,solver,collisionConfiguration);
        dynamicsWorld.setGravity(new Vector3(0,-9.8f,0));

This is how am stepping my simulation:
dynamicsWorld.stepSimulation(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), maxSubSteps,timeStep); 

private static final float yellowBoxMass = 1f;
private static final float timeStep = 1/60f;  //many options I've tried: 1 / 240f, 1 / 300f, 
1/ 30f ..and box still goes through floor
private static final int maxSubSteps =5;  //many options I've tried: 1, 2, 3, 5 ..and box 
still goes through floor
private static final float edgeLengthOfYellowBox=2f;  //many options: 1, 3, 5 and box still 
goes through floor
private static final float heightOfYellowBox=15f; //box starts at a height of 15 
meters/units..I have tried 2, 3, 5, 10, 30, 45

Why a simple simulation cant play the right way! I have followed the tutorial from James T Khan which is clear and to the point. its on this link: youtube  How can I prevent this box from going through the floor?

Use prediction. You know the distances involved. (One knows where everything is at all times; if not, one needs better "asset management") You know the time (accelaration over distance). You script the parts accordingly. Allow physics to do it's thing but set it's duration to what you have pre-determined (time of impact).

@Gerry Schmitz I understand but in the video link tutorial. Since the box is a dynamic rigid body Bullet Physics takes care of the entire motion and it stops it when it hits the ground! I actually have a collision detection method already in place and know the exact time it hits the ground. I just don't know why is not reacting as it should.

Ok I found a solution to my problem. It appears the btRigidBody for my floor instance was not working!
I create a btStaticPlaneShape(which has infinite bounds, Not good! ) and set it just right above my floor instance model.
here is how I create it:
private void CreateMyStaticPlaneShape(){

    Matrix4 m4=new Matrix4();
    m4.idt();
    m4.translate(0,-9,0);

    myStaticPlaneShape = new btStaticPlaneShape(new Vector3(0,1,0),0);
    btMotionState ms = new btDefaultMotionState(m4);
    btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo ci = new btRigidBody.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(0,ms,myStaticPlaneShape);

    btRigidBody r = new btRigidBody(ci);

    dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(r);

}

By changing the following variables, the simulation changes. Such as Jitterinesss when the block hits the static plane and tunneling. These values are working find for now! I need to know how to create a static plane BUT with finite size so I can lay them on top of my floor instances!
private static final float yellowBoxMass = 2;
private static final float timeStep = 1/300f;
private static final int maxSubSteps =10;
private static final float edgeLengthOfYellowBox=2;
private static final float heightOfYellowBox=10;    
private btStaticPlaneShape myStaticPlaneShape;  <---this is making the simulation possible!!

This video from 11 years ago helped me in creating the static plane. Fast foward to around 28:50 old youtube video

There is something odd about using the floorinstance.transform for physics calculations:
by changing the line:
btBodyForFloor.setWorldTransform(floorInstance.transform);  TO:
Matrix4 m44=new Matrix4();
        m44.idt();
        m44.translate(0,-10,0);

        btBodyForFloor.setWorldTransform(m44)/*floorInstance.transform)*/;

AND not including the static plane AT ALL The simulation works!
What could be wrong with the way the floorinstance.transform was used in the calculations!
